# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when training logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logistic_regression_script.py", line 66, in <module>
    svc.fit(X, y)
  File "/Users/t6/opt/anaconda3/envs/envo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py", line 1514, in fit
    accept_large_sparse=solver not in ["liblinear", "sag", "saga"],
  File "/Users/t6/opt/anaconda3/envs/envo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 576, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/Users/t6/opt/anaconda3/envs/envo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 968, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator,
  File "/Users/t6/opt/anaconda3/envs/envo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 738, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am currently trying to feed in features from a numpy array for classification using logistic regression from Scikit-learn.

I have features defined as in `X` as shown for 6 examples:

```
[array([[1.6981133e-07, 3.4315704e-08, 7.1052241e-08, ..., 1.7771872e-02,
         0.0000000e+00, 7.0923954e-01]], dtype=float32)
 array([[3.8282192e-07, 6.9986108e-08, 8.3488118e-08, ..., 2.3458005e-01,
         4.7151586e-01, 2.7263960e-01]], dtype=float32)
 array([[2.6531958e-07, 5.7356804e-08, 8.2255760e-08, ..., 1.5503895e-01,
         2.5217977e-01, 1.4358286e+00]], dtype=float32)
 array([[4.8370327e-07, 4.0322195e-08, 6.0319621e-08, ..., 1.0119628e-02,
         2.8772436e-02, 2.2428477e-01]], dtype=float32)
 array([[4.1497918e-07, 3.5933411e-08, 6.1199998e-08, ..., 2.1676833e-02,
         8.6232759e-03, 1.8828031e-01]], dtype=float32)
 array([[3.4272892e-07, 6.2368358e-08, 7.2425749e-08, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
         2.3943228e-01, 0.0000000e+00]], dtype=float32)]]
```

And labels `y` defined as:

```
[1 0 1 0 1 1]
```

How can I fit this data so it works with the following classifier?

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=5000)
logreg.fit(X, y)
```

I am sure I need to reshape my X arrays but I'm not sure how...

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input and the full error traceback showing where the error occurred.

Comment: From first glance, you are missing `.fit()` on the last line, i.e. `logreg.fit(features, y)`.  And it's not entirely clear how `X` is structured (what each element of `X` is and what is features and what is samples) and what exactly you are trying to achieve with the `reshape` line. What is `features.shape`?

Comment: Hello, please see my edits above. Hopefully it is more clear. I have removed the reshape line as I realised it was doing nothing, but I am sure I need to manipulate the shape of X so that it fits into the classifier...

Comment: You have not added the full traceback and it's still not clear where the error occurs, but if your question is just about how to convert your `X` (a list of arrays of shape `(1, n_features)`) into a 2D array, you can do `X = np.vstack(X)`.

Comment: have you tried what @AlexK proposed? That should give an array with the same rows and your label.

Comment: Ah, ok, I wasn't sure if a whole block of error message would be considered appropriate for the forum. Noted for next time and Yes, I tried it and it works. As an alternative I also applied ```flatten()``` to each row of ```X```. It appears to do the same thing.

Comment: I've edited the above question to include the whole error message.